# вложенный запрос в Mysql update inner join

Tags: sql, запрос

Здесь я должен увеличить price в 2 раза, где прайс больше 100 и вместо этого показать информацию о клиенте, где статус 'delivered' и имя 'ali'

```
UPDATE orders 
SET PRICE=PRICE*2=(
    SELECT
        clients.clients_id,
        name,
        last_name,
        phone,
        address,
        country,
        products_id, 
        STATUS 
    FROM clients
    INNER JOIN ORDERS ON CLIENTS.CLIENTS_ID = ORDERS.CLIENTS_ID
    INNER JOIN countries ON CLIENTS.COUNTRIES_ID = COUNTRIES.COUNTRIES_ID
    WHERE NAME LIKE "%Ali%" AND
          STATUS = "DELIVERED"
)
WHERE name like "%Ali%" and
      STATUS="DELIVERED" AND
      PRICE>100;
```

где ошибка? не могу найти ошибку.

Comment: Удалить весь SELECT вместе с обрамляющими скобками и пред-знаком равенства. Сам SELECT сделать отдельным запросом.

Comment: Вы определитесь, что же вы хотите сделать, изменить данные в таблице или выбрать данные (показать). В MySQL нельзя одновременно и поменять данные и выбрать их. Если надо оба действия - выполняйте их последовательно